# jQuery Plugins and Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I am using a jQuery plugin called Fancy Gallery that often calls images from the images folder within the plugin folder like `background:url("../images/fancygallery/arrows_sprite.png")`. My question has 2 parts

1. How should this plugin integrate with my rails 3.1 application? Should the folder be placed inside the vendors/assets folder? The plugin has 3 folders, css, images, js. If I put these in `vendor/assets/stylesheets`, `vendor/assets/images`, `vendor/assets/javascripts`, the css will surely not be able to locate the images in `../images` folder since it will no longer exist after asset pipelining is done with it. So where should this be placed?
2. Is there a simple way in which I don't have to go in to my plugin and edit the css everywhere it is loading the images? I do not want to do this every time I update the plugin, there has to be a way I can just drop the plugin folder as is and have it work.

**Upon further testing**

This is the issue i am running in to. for example, in the CSS, here is a part that loads the arrow `background: url('../images/fancygallery/arrows_sprite.png')`. Throughout the plugin, all images are referred with a `../images` like that. So when loading the plugin when the page loads, this is how it looks for the image `http://localhost:3000/images/fancygallery/arrows_sprite.png` but the image does not exist there, it exists in the `assets/fancygallery/images` folder. Is there any way I can make the `../images` look in `http://localhost:3000/assets/fancygallery/images/` and not `http://localhost:3000/images/`? Or some other workaround for this that does not require me to alter the plugin code so that I can easily update it later.

**Part of the problem is**

The plugin css is being loaded in my application.css.SCSS file like this

```
@import "fancygallery/css/uniform.aristo";
@import "fancygallery/css/jquery.fancygallery";
@import "fancygallery/css/prettyPhoto";
```

so all images are being relateve to that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by adding a `fancygallery-plugin` folder and then dropping the `fancygallery` folder in there. After `asset:precompile`, the `fancygallery` folder was available in the assets folder. Then I simply called the css and js files directly instead of from inside a application.css.scss file, like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "fancygallery/css/uniform.agent.css" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "fancygallery/css/jquery.fancygallery.css" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "fancygallery/css/prettyPhoto.css" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "fancygallery/js/jquery.uniform.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "fancygallery/js/jquery.fancygallery.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "fancygallery/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" %>
```

This makes the image references just work how the plugin developer intended it to be and they load fine.

Comment: Where did you put the "fancygallery-plugin" folder?